# Owner of app gets wrong access tokens

Tags: node.js, oauth, passport.js, flattr

I stumbled over a strange edge case. I'm not 100% sure if I missed a condition, so it would be interesting if others could reproduce.

- Given I am the owner of an app
- and another Flattr user is connected to this app
- and I connect my Flatrr account with the app
- and I revoke the access to the app in my Flattr account
- and I connect my Flattr account again
- I expect to get an access token for my account, but
- I get the access token for the other connected Flattr account

This occurred when using:
[Passport](http://passportjs.org/) on Node.js with the [passport-flattr strategy](https://github.com/freenerd/passport-flattr)

This setup does not use Basic OAuth on the token endpoint but sends plain Client Credentials instead.

This does not seem to be a security issue, since the owner of the app already has access to all access tokens connected to its app.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce this with our test software. Will try with passport and your strategy.

Comment: This is now reproduced and patched. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the Flattr API that now is patched.